# Efficient approximation of most frequent items across multiple large item-sets

Tags: algorithm, statistics, set, frequency, frequency-analysis

I would like to learn that is there an efficient algorithm that can get the approximate top-k most frequent items across many large item-sets.

> For example, we have 99 sets:
>
> S1 = (i1, i2, i3, i5, i7, i9, ... , i230231)
>
> S2 = (i2, i4, i7, i11, i17, i21, ... , i230231)
>
> S3 = (i1, i5, i9, i12, i13, i55, ... , i334234)
>
> ...
>
> S99 = (i2, i3, i4, i6, i22, i32, ... , i96574)
>
> Want to find the most frequent items. e.g. i2, i1, i3, i7
>
> An underlying assumption is that the items we care about (want to be included in the top-k) will have at least 10% frequency across all sets, so if there are 100 sets, the item we care about should at least appear in 10 sets (hope it can make the problem easier).

A straightforward solution is to build a dictionary with items as keys and their frequencies as values, and iterate through each item-set and increase the frequency count for each item. The problem is it costs linear running time based on the sizes of sets: ∑|Si|. And my item-sets are very large.

I tried to find an approximation by random sampling pairs of sets, and for each pair of sets I make the intersection of them, based on the idea that if an item is frequent enough, it should have a certain frequency across multiple intersections. However it is not faster (if not slower).

Greatly appreciate any ideas, keen to read into researches as well